# Prevent override of default find / search in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, confluence

Is there some way to prevent the default find / search (CTRL+F / CMD+F) in Google Chrome from being overridden?

I've noticed a few applications such as Atlassian Confluence that overrides find with their custom implementation.

Comment: Tumblr does that in their theme editor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll probably need to know some javascript.

If the Confluence site is overriding the `keydown` event using a JS [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), you'll need to write a [userscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) which will [remove the event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) so the functionality is restored to the [captured shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts).

I haven't used Confluence, but if Atlassian has overridden the Find command `ctrl+F / cmd+F`, that is very bad behavior on their part and the best course of action is to contact support and complain about that bad UX.

Comment: Thanks! I looked into it, and you are correct that it is a listener on the keydown event. It is built in to TinyMCE that Confluence use (see example: http://www.tinymce.com/). Only problem is that the keydown listener does a lot of other things too, so just unbinding it will break things.

Comment: @RobinAndersson Good luck sorting it out. You can always re-bind the ones you want to keep.